# Update ListView Record Duplicated Android

Tags: android, android-listview

I put a limit of 15 records to be displayed in my listview. The 15 records successfully displayed but when i clicked on load more button, it add the previous 15 records and the new records too. Here is my async task where more records is being added. I use    articlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); set too but the issue remains. i believe it has something to do with articlesFiltered.size()/15)+1.

```
public class ActusScreen extends BaseActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private DisplayImageOptions options;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String link;
    //...
    final int NONE=0;
    final int THEME=1;
    final int SEARCH=2;
    final int THEME_TO_SEARCH=3;
    final int SEARCH_RESULTS=4;
    final int THEME_TO_SEARCH_RESULTS=5;
    int MODE=NONE;

    public ArrayList<Article> articles;
    public ArrayList<Article> articlesFiltered;
    public ArrayList<Theme> themes;
    public ArrayList<Theme> themeFiltered;

    public static int titleIndex=0;
    static boolean original_view = false;

    RelativeLayout adLayout;
    ListView themesList;
    RelativeLayout searchLayout;
    EditText searchField;
    Button back, theme;

    StringBuilder builder;

    ScrollView scrollme;

    ThemesAdapter themeAdapter;
    ArticlesAdapter articlesAdapter;
    TextView header_text;
    ActusScreen context;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    ImageView image_actus;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.actus);
        context=this;

        back=(Button)findViewById(R.id.envoye);
        back.setOnClickListener(this);
        back.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        theme=(Button)findViewById(R.id.theme);
        theme.setOnClickListener(this);
        Button search=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
        search.setOnClickListener(this);

        header_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_titre);
        header_text.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.actus).toString());

        adLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.adLayout);

        themeAdapter=new ThemesAdapter(this);
        themesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.themesList);
        themesList.setAdapter(themeAdapter);
        themesList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        SelectedArticle.mtypo=1;

        articlesAdapter=new ArticlesAdapter(this);
        ListView articlesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.articlesList);
        articlesList.setAdapter(articlesAdapter);

        searchLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.searchLayout);
        searchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        searchField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.keyword);
        Button valid=(Button)findViewById(R.id.valid);
        valid.setOnClickListener(this);


        new GetAllArticlesTask().execute();

        image_actus = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
        image_actus.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String url = link;
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    //  .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(3))
        .cacheInMemory()
        .cacheOnDisc()
        .build();

        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(getApplicationContext()));

        new backTask().execute("");
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //FavoriteScreen.flagx=1;
        super.onStart();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.envoye:
            back();
            break;
        case R.id.theme:
            if(themesList.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE)
                themesList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                themesList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
        case R.id.search:
            search();
            break;
        case R.id.valid:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if(MODE==SEARCH)
                MODE=SEARCH_RESULTS;
            else
                MODE=THEME_TO_SEARCH_RESULTS;
            filterArticles();
            break;
        }
    }

    public void search(){
        switch(MODE){
        case SEARCH_RESULTS:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MODE=SEARCH;
            break;
        case THEME_TO_SEARCH_RESULTS:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MODE=THEME_TO_SEARCH;
            break;
        case THEME:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MODE=THEME_TO_SEARCH;
            break;
        case NONE:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            theme.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            MODE=SEARCH;
            break;

        }
    }

    public void back(){
        switch(MODE){
        case SEARCH_RESULTS:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MODE=SEARCH;
            break;
        case THEME_TO_SEARCH_RESULTS:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            MODE=THEME_TO_SEARCH;
            break;
        case THEME:

            back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            theme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            /*
             * 
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
            */

             articlesAdapter=new ArticlesAdapter(this);
             ListView articlesList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.articlesList);
             articlesList.setAdapter(articlesAdapter);
            //ActusScreen.titleIndex=0;
             ArticlesAdapter.mode = true;
             titleIndex=0;

             new GetAllArticlesTask().execute();

             header_text.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.actus).toString());

            MODE=NONE;

            break;
        case SEARCH:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            theme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            MODE=NONE;

            copyArticles();
            articlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        case THEME_TO_SEARCH:
            searchLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            MODE=THEME;
            copyArticles();
            articlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void copyArticles() {
        if(articles!=null){
            if(articlesFiltered==null)
                articlesFiltered=new ArrayList<Article>();
            else
                articlesFiltered.clear();
            for(Article a: articles)
                articlesFiltered.add(a);
            }
        }


    public void filterArticles(){

        String key=searchField.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        if(key.length()>0){

            if(articlesFiltered!=null){
                articlesFiltered.clear();
                System.gc();
            }

            for(Article a: articles){
                if(a.name.toLowerCase().contains(key))
                    articlesFiltered.add(a);
            }

            articlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    private class GetAllArticlesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            if(Globals.themes==null)
                Globals.themes=HTTPFunctions.getThemesList();

            if(articles!=null){
                articles.clear();
                System.gc();
            }

            articles=HTTPFunctions.getAllArticles();
            copyArticles();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            articlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            themeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     }

    private class GetThemeArticlesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            if(articles!=null){
                articles.clear();
                System.gc();

            }

            articles=HTTPFunctions.getThemeArticles(params[0]);

            //begin 06/03; articles.theme_id not set by HTTPFunctions when a specific theme is selected; need to set it explicitly
            for (Article a : articles)
                a.theme_id=params[0];
            //end
            System.out.println("theme article: "+ HTTPFunctions.getThemeArticles(params[0]));
            copyArticles();

            return null;


        }


        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            articlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     }

    private class GetMoreArticlesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        public Void doInBackground(Void... params) {


            ArrayList<Article>moreArticles=HTTPFunctions.getMoreArticles(addOne((articlesFiltered.size()/15)));         

            if(moreArticles!=null){
                articles.addAll(articles);
                copyArticles();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", context.getResources().getString(R.string.loading), true, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
            articlesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
     }

    public void articleSelected(int id){
        Globals.copyArticles(articlesFiltered);
        Intent i=new Intent(context, SelectedArticle.class);
        i.putExtra("id", id);
        //begin
        //i.putExtra("title", ArticlesAdapter.selected);

        if (titleIndex==0){

            String title=Util.getTitleName(articlesFiltered.get(id).type, articlesFiltered.get(id).theme_id);
            i.putExtra("title", title); 
        }
        else{

            String title=ArticlesAdapter.selected.toUpperCase();
            i.putExtra("title", title); 
        }

        //end
        context.startActivity(i);
    }

    public void themeSelected(int id){
        themesList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        MODE=THEME;
        theme.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        back.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArticlesAdapter.mode = false;

        //begin 06/03
        //ArticlesAdapter.selected=Globals.themes.get(id).name;
        //header_text.setText(Globals.themes.get(id).name.toUpperCase());

        Spanned name=Html.fromHtml(Globals.themes.get(id).name);

        System.out.println("spanned name: "+ name);

        ArticlesAdapter.selected=name.toString().toUpperCase();
        header_text.setText(name.toString().toUpperCase());
        //end

        System.out.println("theme_name: "+ Globals.themes.get(id).name);
        new GetThemeArticlesTask().execute(Globals.themes.get(id).id);
    }

    public void loadMore(){
        new GetMoreArticlesTask().execute();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if (original_view==true){

                new GetAllArticlesTask().execute();
                theme.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                back.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                header_text.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.actus).toString());
                original_view=false;
          }

          super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        SelectedReglementation.setview=true;

        super.onPause();

    }


     class backTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Post>> {

          @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              super.onPreExecute();
        }
          @Override
            protected ArrayList<Post> doInBackground(String... urls) {

              ArrayList<Post> newpostarraylist=new ArrayList<Post>();

              try{

                     URL url = new URL("");
                        BufferedReader reader = null;
                        builder = new StringBuilder();
                        try {
                            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
                            for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) {
                                builder.append(line.trim());
                            }
                        } finally {
                            if (reader != null) try { reader.close(); } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
                        }

                        System.out.println("Builder: "+ builder);

                        }catch(Exception ex){}

                return newpostarraylist;
            }

          @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Post> result) {

                        String[] banner_image = builder.toString().split(";");
                        imageLoader.displayImage(banner_image[2], image_actus,options);
                        link = banner_image[1];

                }
            }



     public int addOne(int i){
            return i+1;
        }


}
```

and My article adapter

```
public class ArticlesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    ActusScreen main;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;
    String imageUrl="";
    public static String selected="";
    public static boolean mode=false;
    int x=0;

    //disable a.theme_id null pointer wh
    public static int bine=0;

    public ArticlesAdapter(ActusScreen m) {
        main=m;
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(m);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        if(main.articlesFiltered!=null)
            return main.articlesFiltered.size();
        return 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView==null) {
            convertView=newView(position, parent);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            holder.remove=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
            holder.title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.text_title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_title);
            holder.more=(RelativeLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.moreLayout);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Article a=main.articlesFiltered.get(position);

        imageLoader.DisplayImage(String.format(imageUrl, a.image), holder.image);


        String str = a.name;

        int length = str.length();

        String newStr = a.name;

        if (length>65)
            newStr = str.replaceAll("^(.{74})(.*)$","$1...");

        holder.title.setText(Html.fromHtml(newStr));

        holder.text_title.setText(selected.toUpperCase());
        holder.remove.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        if (holder.text_title.equals(null))
            holder.text_title.setText("t");

        if(position==main.articlesFiltered.size()-1 && main.articlesFiltered.size()<=45  && main.articlesFiltered.size()%15==0)
            holder.more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
            holder.more.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                main.articleSelected(position);
                SelectedArticle.mtypo=1;
            }

        });

        holder.more.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                main.loadMore();
            }
        });


        if (ActusScreen.titleIndex==0){
        ...

         }

        }

        return(convertView);
    }

    private View newView(int position, ViewGroup parent) {
        return(main.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.articles_row, parent, false));
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView image, remove;
        TextView title;
        TextView text_title;
        RelativeLayout more;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 
and the HttpFunction getMoreArticles()**

```
public static ArrayList<Article> getMoreArticles(int page){
        String url=LAST_ARTICLE_URL;
        if(url.endsWith(".php"))
            url+="?page="+page;
        else
            url+="&page="+page;
        String response=getResponse(url);
        if(!ERROR.equals(response)){
            return JsonParsingFunctions.parseArticles(response);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you meaning to do articles.addAll(articles);  Is that not just duplicating the articles already in the array?

Comment: yes it duplicating the articles already in the arraylist but i want to display ony part of it and display new data every time load more is pressed.

Comment: So can you clarify what you're doing?  You initially populate the list with your first 15 articles and that is it. Then you can click load more and 15 more are downloaded from the server?  Why do you duplicate the initial 15 articles in the arrayList? Not very memory efficient? Memory use will be exponential with loads...  So after clicking loadmore once, you now have 45 articles in the arraylist (15 + 30) and what do you want to do? Just show the new 15 in the listView? Or have all 30 but set the view to be showing the last 15?

Comment: i want to show the 15 previous + 15 new item without duplicating   the previous 15 records e.g. first load: 15 records; second load: 15 old+15 new; third load: 30 + 15 ...

Comment: So what is the state of moreArticles after ArrayList<Article> moreArticles=HTTPFunctions.getMoreArticles((articlesFiltered.size()/15)+1); Does this only return the 15 new articles?

Comment: when i log articlesFiltered.size() i get 15 items and for articlesFiltered.size()/15)+1 it returns 11 items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening is concatenation in the method call.   articlesFiltered.size()/15 is giving 1, then the +1 is not ADDING 1, it is concatenating 1, i.e 1+1 = 11 NOT 2. You could create a method

```
public int addOne(int i){
    return i+1;
}
```

and use

```
ArrayList<Article>moreArticles=HTTPFunctions.getMoreArticles(addOne((articlesFiltered.size()/15)));
```

That should work providing the rest of the code is good

Comment: i did it whay you say still duplicate the previous 15 records

Comment: can you add the code for the getMoreArticles method to the question? Would probably be able to help from that

Comment: look at my question i post the whole class

Comment: You have a method HTTPFunctions.getMoreArticles() which you reference to actually get the articles yes?  Can you post THAT code so I can see what you actually fetch and return.  I think your problem is with articles.addAll(articles);
That code just takes the arrayList of all items in articles, and adds it to the back of the List. For example if you have ArrayList<int> items = [0,1,2]; and do items.addAll(items);, afterwards you will have items = [0,1,2,0,1,2];  I don't think this is what you meant to do

Comment: ok i'll post it in less than 10 seconds but its only taking a json file

Comment: its working your're right just change articles.addAll(articles);  to     articles.addAll(moreArticles); made it :) thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

what variable is your adapter?

you notify your adapter but i don't see that you add datas to your articlesAdapter

Comment: check my updated question. There is another async task which  GetAllArticlesTask. then when i clicked on a row in the adapter, getmore async task is called

Comment: it's posbile when you do "articles.addAll(articles);" you duplicate the datas...if you have 15 items in articles and you do "articles.addAll(articles)" you have 15 items + the same 15 items. can it be possible?

Comment: Imagine you have this list: numbers = {1,2,3,4}. If you do "numbers.addAll(numbers)", at the end of that numbers'll have these datas: numbers = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4}.